# JS add text to input if it isn't in already

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to get a button click to add the data of one field to another if it isn't in there already, I think I'm close but, in my example, if my 'else if' parses, a second click will make my 'else' parse also. can't quite figure this one out.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    var replied = $('#en_replied');
    var mem_id = $('#enr_member_id').val();

    if (mem_id.indexOf(replied.val())) {
        var replied_ids = replied.val();
    } else if (!replied.val()) {
        var replied_ids = mem_id;
    } else {
        var replied_ids = replied.val() + '|' + mem_id;
    }
    replied.val(replied_ids);
});
```

I've also set up a js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sheferd/bq9o57fg/1/

Thanks

Comment: mem_id.indexOf(replied.val()) will return index which be 0 and 0 inside if treated as false.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to check with `mem_id.indexOf(replied.val())`

Comment: I'm trying to see if a current members ID (stored in a field) is already inside another field and if it isn't add it. from further tests, turns out what I have is completly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Just compare the member id against the value of the text input box.

```
var old_data; //will hold old data until it is reassigned

$('#test').click(function(){
  var replied = $('#en_replied').val();
  var mem_id = $('#enr_member_id').val();

  if (replied !== mem_id) {
    //set textbox value to mem_id
    old_data = $('#en_replied').val();
    alert('Old Data: '+old_data);
    $('#en_replied').val(mem_id);
  } else {
    //values already match
    alert('values match');
  }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLy61xdr/3/)

If you needed to store the old #en_replied data continously and use it, you could change old data to an array and check for the values.  Something along the lines of:

```
var old_data = [10,11,17,23];
var presentValue;

presentValue = old_data.indexOf(17); //returns 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I also need to keep any data that exists in the #en_replied field

Comment: You can do that if you grab that data before reassigning

Comment: Partly my fault here, but the way the 'old data' is stored will never match the new data unless it is that exactly. my old_data would be '10|11|17|23' and I need to see if 17 is within that before adding or not

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I'm happy with, I'm sure my js can be refined but this works for me:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    var replied = $('#en_replied');
    var mem_id = $('#enr_member_id').val();

var hasReplied = replied.val().split('|')

for(var i = 0; i < hasReplied.length; i++) {

    if(hasReplied[i] == mem_id){
    var hasId = true;
  };     
};

if(hasId !== true){
    replied_ids = replied.val() + '|' + mem_id;
};

    replied.val(replied_ids);

});
```

**Made a jsfiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/bq9o57fg/6/